# adding dropdown list for django

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django right now and I try to add a dropdown list to the website.
The website right now will show a list of games. The dropdown list has different platforms and I want the game list change after the user selects one platform. What should I do?

At `form.py`:

```
class platformSelectForm(forms.Form):
    platformsList = (
        ('all', 'Please Select'),
        ('NS', 'Nintendo Switch'),
        ('PS4', 'PlayStation4'),
        ('PS5', 'PlayStation5'),
        ('XBO', 'Xbox One'),
        ('XS', 'Xbox Series S/X'),
    );
    platforms_Select = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.Select, choices = platformsList, required = False);
```

At `view.py`:

```
class showGameLists(TemplateView):
    template_name = "showList/home.html"
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs);
        platformSelect = platformSelectForm(self.request.POST or None);
        context['platformSelect'] = platformSelect;
        games = getGames(nowDay.year, nowDay.month, platforms);
        context['games'] = games;
        context['year'] = nowDay.year;
        context['month'] = calendar.month_name[nowDay.month];
        context['prevMonth'] = prevMonth(nowDay);
        context['nextMonth'] = nextMonth(nowDay);
 return context
```

At urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path;
from .views import showGameLists;

urlpatterns = [
    path('', showGameLists.as_view(), name='home')
]
```

At home.html:

```
<form method = 'POST' action = '/'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ platformSelect.as_p }}
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>

    {% for game in games %}
    <div>
        <span><h2>{{game.0}}</h2>
        <p>Release Date: {{ game.1 }}, Metacritic: {{ game.3 }}</p>
        <p>Platform: {% for platform in game.2 %}{{ platform }}/{% endfor %}</p>
        {% if game.4 %}
        <img src={{game.4}} width="367" height="204">
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

right now, I can show the list and submit button.
But I try lots of ways to get the value from the drop list, but it also wrong me:

```
[17/Jan/2021 11:15:29] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 0
Method Not Allowed (POST): /
Method Not Allowed: /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a `Method Not Allowed (POST)` error because you are using a `TemplateView` to submit a `POST` request, instead you should use `FormView` like this:

```
class showGameLists(FormView):
    template_name = "showList/home.html"
    form_class = platformSelectForm # pass your form class here
    
    def form_valid():
        form.save() # process form submit
        return redirect('view_to_redirect_to')
```

Comment: Yes I know, but if I change to the FormView, what about others?

Comment: What about others what? Can you explain? This should work, there is no reason to use `TemplateView` unless you want to only display some raw `html` data. Plus you can inherit from multiple `CBV`s.

Comment: I mean, about the list I show on the webpage(the  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): part), what should I change at this part that makes it show normally?

Comment: you can use `get_context_data` in `FormView` as well